# In android using YouTube Player API Reference for iframe Embeds shows error MediaPlayer(4469): Error (1,-2147483648)

Tags: javascript, android, iframe, video, youtube

In android **webview** im playing youtube video using **YouTube Player API** Reference for iframe Embeds shows error **MediaPlayer(4469): Error (1,-2147483648)**

Link for YouTube Player API :[link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)

i searched for this `error(MediaPlayer(4469): Error (1,-2147483648))` i couldn't found in some links it said that that url may be wrong in that `Videoview and permission` need to be added in `AndroidManifest.xml` like that only but thats not my problem

Problem is in **Network** that for lengthy videos that network not supported. so it shows  `MediaPlayer(4469): Error (1,-2147483648) How to handle the Error`

any help will appreciated!

Comment: Can you please post your entire code.